# Paragraph not changing with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I have the following HTML code. The div which contains the `.sc_services_item_description` class, needs to be changed with javascript. So I tried the following:

```js
target = document.querySelector('.sc_services_item_description p')
target.innerHTML = "Paragraph text changed!"
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate" data-style="width:100%;" style="width: 250px; position: relative;" data-swiper-slide-index="2">
  <div class="sc_services_item_wrap">
    <div id="sc_services_1448898461_3" class="sc_services_item sc_services_item_3 odd">
      <div class="sc_services_item_featured post_featured">
      </div>
      <div class="sc_services_item_content">
        <h4 class="sc_services_item_title"><a href="http://sifaclinic.nl/wordpress/services/acupunctuur/">Acupunctuur</a></h4>
        <div class="sc_services_item_description">
          <p>Een bewezen behandelmethode die stamt uit de Traditionele Chinese Geneeswijze.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it's not working. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

edit: works over here, but not on my [website](http://sifaclinic.nl/wordpress/therapieen/).

Comment: I added your code to a snippet, yet it works absolutely fine. Please check the console for errors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Here it does, but not on my site. Could you try it over there too? Will add the site to my post. It's about the paragraph's in the light blue slider.

Comment: When exactly is it supposed to change?

Comment: The problem is because the content of the slider is dynamically generated by the plugin after the page has loaded. You need to run your code *after* that has happened. Exactly how you do that depends on the plugin you're using. The best solution though would be to edit the content in the source directly instead of using JS as a crutch.

Comment: @Xufox when the page is loaded.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I really need to solve this, how should I do this?